# alcatel onetouch FierceXL battery is draining too fast

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, alcatel-one-touch-idol-s

I've only had my onetouch for 3 weeks now and all of a sudden the battery started draining rapidly, even when I plug it into the charger, and charging very slowly. If i use the phone at all when its plugged in it'll say it's charging for a few minutes, then start to drain rapidly(full charge gone in 30 minutes or less) even though the charge light is on and it says it's charging. If I don't use the phone at all while plugged into charger it charges very slowly(after being plugged in all night it was only at 29%). If I use the phone when its not plugged in it still drains faster than it used to, though not as fast as it does if I use the phone while plugged in. This started happening 3 days ago. like right now I've been plugged in for almost 2 hours and it's still only at 1% and has died 2 times while trying to send this question.

Comment: Possible common reasons-faulty charger/USB cord/poor connection/battery NOT holding charge are not applicable in your case being a new phone . It is presumably covered by warranty so take a back up of your data and send in the phone for replacement.

Comment: After thought- This is on wall charger correct? - earlier comment for "not applicable" read " unlikely". (Even if one of those is culprit,it is better to have it checked out by service center guys rather than fault finding and ending up replacing on your own)